# How to get boundary of zoomed & paned svg in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out the topleft and bottomright coordinates after zooming and panning svg in d3. I have object moving inside the svg so I can decide if the object point is moving outside the  current zoomed/panned view and do panning dynamically.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried already and provide a minimal, verifiable & complete test case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 0,0 point lies in the center of the screen by default:

```
const screenToVirtual = (point, transform) => {
    const x = (point.x - transform.x) / transform.k - svgWidth/2;
    const y = (point.y - transform.y) / transform.k - svgHeight/2;
    return {x, y};
};

const onZoom = transform => {
  const screenTopLeft = {x: 0, y: 0};
  const screenBottonRight = {x: svgWidth, y: svgHeight}
  const topLeft = screenToVirtual(screenTopLeft, transform);  
  const bottomRight = screenToVirtual(screenBottomRight, transform);  
}

d3.zoom()
  ...
  .on('zoom', e => onZoom(e.transform));
```